# C++ : Disabling a device driver in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, driver, wmi

Can anybody help me to tell why this code is not disabling the `cdrom driver`?It builds correctly.I debugged each line everything works perfectly. I have removed the error handling code and the cleanup code.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

     IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;
 HRESULT hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL,-1,NULL,NULL,RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,NULL,EOAC_NONE,NULL);    
    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator,0,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_IWbemLocator,LPVOID *)&pLoc);

    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"),NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0,0,&pSvc);

    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"StopService");
    BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"Win32_SystemDriver");

    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);
    IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, &pInParamsDefinition, NULL);

    VARIANT varCommand;

    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(L"Win32_SystemDriver.Name=\"cdrom\"", MethodName, 0,
    NULL,NULL, &pOutParams, NULL);

    VARIANT varReturnValue;
    hres = pOutParams->Get(L"ReturnValue", 0, &varReturnValue, NULL, 0);
    if (!FAILED(hres))
    wcout << "ReturnValue " << varReturnValue.intVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&varReturnValue);

    // Clean up    
    SysFreeString(ClassName);
    SysFreeString(MethodName);  
    return 0;
}
```

Please help..

Comment: The mechanics of sending the stop command are working, but it's returning "2" which is probably a failure. If it could be stopped, a simple "net stop cdrom" would work, but it doesn't. Note that there may be other drivers/services associated with this device that show up in the device manager.

Comment: I tried `USBSTOR` and `FloppyDisk` instead of `cdrom`.. nothing works..

Comment: Is it okay if you have to reboot? You could just change the start type to demand or disabled, e.g. open elevated command prompt and run `sc config cdrom start= demand` (Also, this tool http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/serviwin.html makes it pretty easy to reconfigure services)

Comment: I cannot reboot the system.. And The return value is `4` when the code is executed with admin privilege. But from `stopservice` documentation, it tells that  `4 : The requested control code is not valid, or it is unacceptable to the service.`

Comment: Have you unmounted filesystems? I'd expect that you can't disable a driver which is in use.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes.. i checked it also.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all windows driver accept a 'stop' control request even if they say they do. You can not stop cdrom driver even from a command-line running as an administrator like: "sc stop cdrom".

To disable a windows driver, one must set it to SERVICE_DEMAND_START and reboot. Again, you may not be able to disable all drivers. Some drivers have an Error control of 0x3, which means that windows will fallback to last known good control set if those drivers fail to start.

It might be a good idea to try your code with a service/driver that is can be stopped from an administrative command prompt. 
Moreover, you may want to check "AcceptStop" property before Executing the "StopService" method.

You might also want to CoSetProxyBlanket as mentioned in the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I tried `AcceptStop` and `Started` using `WMICodeCreator` and both values return `true` for `cdrom`.